# Unexpected behavior from python's relativedelta

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, timestamp, relativedelta

I'm getting a confusing result when using Python's timestamps and

> my_timestamp

`Timestamp('2015-06-01 00:00:00')`

> my_timestamp + relativedelta(month = +4)

`Timestamp('2015-04-01 00:00:00')`

Naturally I expected the output to `Timestamp('2015-10-01 00:00:00')`

What is the correct way to add "months" to dates?

---

[EDIT]: I've since solved this by using the following (in case anyone in Pandas has the same problem):

> print my_timestamp
>   print my_timestamp + DateOffset(months=4)

`2015-06-01 00:00:00`
`2015-10-01 00:00:00`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that you are using the wrong keyword argument.  You want `months` instead of `month`.

Per [the documentation](http://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/relativedelta.html), `month` denotes absolute information (not relative) and simply replaces the given information, as you are noting.  Using `months` denotes relative information, and performs the calculation as you'd expect:

```
Timestamp('2015-06-01 00:00:00') + relativedelta(months=4)

2015-10-01 00:00:00
```

Comment: Daaamn. Faced this problem too. Horrible naming decision.